# Modelling temperature: seasonality, stationarity, differencing

Tags: time-series, stationarity, seasonality, acf-pacf, differencing

I have temperature-related time daily time series. I plot the time series and found that the plot have seasonal variations. Thus I differenced the series.

[image]

When I did Dickey-Fuller test for both temperature and differenced temperature using `ur.df`, the results say that both time series are stationary.

Dickey-Fuller test for differenced temperature:

```r
y_tempmax<-diff(production$tempmax, lag = 1, differences =1 )
summary(ur.df(y_tempmax, lags=1, type='trend'))#drift

############################################### 
# Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root Test # 
############################################### 

Test regression trend 

Call:
lm(formula = z.diff ~ z.lag.1 + 1 + tt + z.diff.lag)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-11.1515  -0.9934  -0.0003   1.0565   9.1865 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  1.353e-02  7.477e-02   0.181    0.856    
z.lag.1     -1.593e+00  3.436e-02 -46.375   <2e-16 ***
tt          -8.498e-06  6.172e-05  -0.138    0.891    
z.diff.lag   2.260e-01  2.131e-02  10.606   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.71 on 2092 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6676,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6671 
F-statistic:  1401 on 3 and 2092 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16


Value of test-statistic is: -46.3754 716.8953 1075.342 

Critical values for test statistics: 
      1pct  5pct 10pct
tau3 -3.96 -3.41 -3.12
phi2  6.09  4.68  4.03
phi3  8.27  6.25  5.34
```

Dickey-Fuller test for temperature:

```r
summary(ur.df(production$tempmax, lags=1, type='trend'))#drift

############################################### 
# Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root Test # 
############################################### 

Test regression trend 

Call:
lm(formula = z.diff ~ z.lag.1 + 1 + tt + z.diff.lag)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-11.6277  -1.0295  -0.0107   1.0514   9.4926 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  6.259e+00  8.239e-01   7.596 4.56e-14 ***
z.lag.1     -6.946e-02  9.123e-03  -7.613 4.01e-14 ***
tt          -4.207e-05  6.260e-05  -0.672    0.502    
z.diff.lag  -2.650e-01  2.107e-02 -12.576  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.731 on 2093 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1143,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.113 
F-statistic:    90 on 3 and 2093 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16


Value of test-statistic is: -7.6135 19.3307 28.9914 

Critical values for test statistics: 
      1pct  5pct 10pct
tau3 -3.96 -3.41 -3.12
phi2  6.09  4.68  4.03
phi3  8.27  6.25  5.34
```

But when I draw ACF and PACF plot for temperature, I get this:

[image]

And for differenced temperature, I get this:

[image]

I also did `auto.arima` for original temperature series to find suitable model. I got the following results:

```r
summary(a_tempmax)

Series: production$tempmax 
ARIMA(2,0,1) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
         ar1      ar2      ma1     mean
      1.2924  -0.3013  -0.7346  89.4272
s.e.  0.0404   0.0391   0.0301   1.0500

sigma^2 = 2.776:  log likelihood = -4049.1
AIC=8108.2   AICc=8108.23   BIC=8136.44

Training set error measures:
                      ME     RMSE     MAE         MPE     MAPE      MASE        ACF1
Training set 0.006608083 1.664633 1.27077 -0.02703688 1.419712 0.9228368 0.003088886
```

Do I need to difference the original temperature series to make it stationary? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does temperature have a unit root? Probably not. Why would you difference a variable that does not have a unit root? Doing that introduces a unit-root moving-average component. Instead, model the seasonality in temperature deterministically using Fourier terms or dummy variables. You can include them in `auto.arima` via the argument `xreg`. For a more detailed explanation and for R code, see ["Forecasting with long seasonal periods"](https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/longseasonality/) by Rob J. Hyndman.

Comment: Thank you @Richard Hardy . It solved my issue

Comment: and @Richard Hardy thank you for editing my question

Comment: @soba, you are welcome! As an experienced user on the site, I am trying to contribute in multiple ways.